# Updating collection field in a Rails form based on input to a previous field in the same form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, collections

I'm a hobbyist on my first project.  In a form, oranizers can select multiple events in a collection select.   I want these events to be available as choices in an array field checkbox collection further down in the same form.

First, organizer selects the events:

```
<%= f.input :events, collection: @organizer.events.order(:start_time).reverse, label_method: :event_name_and_date, input_html: {multiple: true, id: "event_select"} %>
```

Then, this checkbox collection field (and others like it in the form) should dynamically update with the previously selected events as options, so the ids of the checked off events get sent in the param array.

```
<%= f.input :events_to_include_in_event_pass_1, :collection => ["(previously selected events", "etc"], :as => :check_boxes, include_hidden: false, :input_html => {:multiple => true, id: "event_pass_select"} %>
```

I've got an ajax:

```
$('#event_select').on('change', function(){
  var grab_events = $('#event_select').val();
  var hpeData = '{"hpe": "' + grab_events + '"}';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url:'/events/get_the_e',
    dataType:'json',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: hpeData,
    success:function (data) {
      ... $("document.forms["eventForm"]["events_to_include_in_event_pass_1"].collection_value(?)").update_with('data.hpe.each.event_name_... and_id_somehow_gets_added')
    }
  });
}
```

which brings back the instances selected in the first collection field, but I don't know how to dynamcially change #event_pass_select collection with these instances.  ... is this even possible?  Or is there some general better way to set something like this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize the input_html was in fact working, it just applied the id to each checkbox, instead of the whole input.   I figured that out by clicking 'edit as html' in ctrl c.  I also saw all the html that makes up each checkbox, and thought I would try putting all that in there, instead of just option, and it worked. These are probably a result of simpleform?  I appreciate the help dbugger.

```
$('#event_select').on('change', function(){
  var asdf = 1;
  $("#event_select option:selected").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).html();

    if (asdf === 1) {
        $(".festival_multipass_ticket_1_hpe span").empty(); 
        $(".festival_multipass_ticket_1_hpe").append( $('<span class="checkbox"><label for="festival_multipass_ticket_1_hpe_' + asdf + '"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="' + val + '" name="festival[multipass_ticket_1_hpe][]">' + text + '</label></span>')
        );
    } else {
        $(".festival_multipass_ticket_1_hpe").append( $('<span class="checkbox"><label for="festival_multipass_ticket_1_hpe_' + asdf + '"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="' + val + '" name="festival[multipass_ticket_1_hpe][]">' + text + '</label></span>')
        );
    }

  asdf += 1;
});
```

Comment: well, this doesn't put in additional checkboxes if multiple event_select are selected, but i'll work on it.

Comment: ffffffffixed it

Answer (score 1):

Don't need an ajax call -- that's taking the data from the browser, sending it back to the server, then updating the browser.

A little jQuery will do the trick. Read through the selected options and use them to fill the desired input. Something like this...

```
$('#event_select').on('change', function(){
  $("#event_pass_select").empty();
  $("#event_select option:selected").each(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).html();
    $("#event_pass_select").append( $("<option>")
      .val(val)
      .html(text)
    );
  });
});
```

Change '#event_pass_select' to the appropriate control id on your form.

Comment: Thank you... that displays a string of the id below the current checkboxes (ie. '53'), possibly because I omitted the fact that I'm using simpleform?    If this was a regular collection input, would that put the id as another checkbox option?

Comment: @daveasdf Updated to get both the id and text

Comment: What I meant was - it doesn't add it as an checkbox option in the collect, it just puts the text below the current existing checkboxes.

Comment: Also, $("#event_pass_select").empty(); clears out the whole input.   how can you add options to nothing?

Comment: i think the problem may stem from my inability to set the id for the input.  simple form input_html doesn't work.

Comment: Can work around it with jQuery, id is not the only selector, can use name and class too.